# How to retrieve data's name in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm not sure if "data's name" is the correct way to call it but here is my problem:

I have a table like this

[image]

I want to create 2 arrays that contain the ID (`0001, 0040`) and the Date (`13-9-2017`).

Because IDs are generated automatically so I don't know how to query

What I've tried:

```swift
func retrievingPresciptionID(){
        let userID = appDelegate.userIDFirebase
        Database
            .database()
            .reference()
            .child("UserInformation")
            .child(userID)
            .child("prescriptionID")
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
                if snapshot.exists(){
                    for id in snapshot.children {
                        self.prescriptionID.append((id as AnyObject).key)
                    }
                    print(self.prescriptionID)
                }else{
                    print("snapshot failed")
                }
            })
    }
```

It printed `snapshot failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we get the dict for the prescriptionIDs..

```
for prescription in prescriptionIDs { 
  IDArray.append(prescription.key)
  dateArray.append(prescription.value) 
}
```

The problem is you are not getting your dict to create your two arrays. Find the node that is missing.

Comment: I updated the post. I think my code is the same as you and it didn't work

Comment: Why does your snapshot not exist? Is it not finding the child prescriptionID? Put a breakpoint at the root and manually go down the tree. For instance, if you are on the userID node, you can use po snapshot["prescriptionID"]

Comment: I'm so dumb. It couldn't find the child prescriptionID as you said and I checked the database again. Apparently, I was on the userID that doesn't have any prescription so no ID yet. Thanks for the help anyway